# What's a good way to run a point-to-point network speed test over a WAN?

Tags: performance, monitoring, powershell, wide-area-network

I want to monitor my WAN speed between two offices, and be able to schedule it to run at certain times of the day.

I guess in its simplest form this is just a point to point copy, but I want to automate it so I can schedule it to run at certain times.

Are there any tools out there? I also wondered about doing this with Powershell.

Comment: If you just want to monitor latency, I'd suggest [SmokePing](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) for *nix, or [PingMonitor](http://emcosoftware.com/ping-monitor) for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

[iperf](https://code.google.com/p/iperf-cygwin/) is a great tool for testing bandwidth. It's natively a *nix application, but it looks like it has been ported to cygwin, so should be able to be run in windows as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget [PSPing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx).

It's a command-line tool, which makes it inherently automatable. Does latency and bandwidth tests. Written by the master NT geek.

Answer (score 0):

- Ixia QCheck
- PCATTP
- SNMP monitoring at the endpoint routers
- NetStress
- NTttcp
- SmokePing

etc. etc.